# What does int ai = a[i], j; do?

Tags: java

I am working on an insertion sort problem from a code i got from my instructor, but i do not know what this means (int ai = a[i], j;)

```java
public static void sort(int[] a) {
 // POSTCONDITION: a[0] <= a[1] <= ... <= a[a.length-1];
 for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) { // step 1
   int ai = a[i], j; // step 2
   for (j = i; j > 0 && a[j-1] > ai; j--) { // step 3
     a[j] = a[j-1]; // step 4
   }
   a[j] = ai; // step 5
   // INVARIANT: a[0] <= a[1] <= ... <= a[i];
 }
```

Comment: it declares 2 variables. The first is initialized.

Comment: Step 1 could just as easily (and perhaps more readable) been: `for (int i = 1, j; i < a.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 6):

```
int ai = a[i], j;
```

This declares a variable `ai`, initialized to the value `a[i]`; and an uninitialized variable `j`.

Declaring two or more variables in the same statement is considered by some to be confusing, and should be avoided (e.g. it is [banned by Google's style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.8.2-variable-declarations)).

Comment: Thank you, but what will the value of 'ai' be  and how does this affect 'j'.

Comment: @HanisHapsa the value of `ai` is whatever the value of `a[i]` is when the statement is executed. It has no effect whatsoever on `j` (and vice versa).

Answer (score 4):

You can declare variables like this

```
int a, b;
```

You can assign variables like this

```
int a = 10, b = 10;
```

So the code

```
int ai = a[i], j;
```

declares two variables (`ai` and `j`), but only assign `ai` with the value `a[i]`.